# Finding N-Most Similar Organizations to a Given Organization

Tags: r, clustering, k-nearest-neighbour

I am looking to provide a model with one data point and have it return the observations most similar to that given data point.

I am in the process of developing peer groups from a dataset of 240 nonprofit organizations and I have performed several types of cluster analysis on the data, including hierarchical and k-means, but I am not too happy with the results so far. However, I do have in mind a few organizations that I feel would be a perfect fit to build a peer group around. My question: what technique would I use to find the n-most similar organizations to a given, single organization?

I am not concerned with cluster size. I am looking to provide the model with one data point and have it return the observations most similar to that given data point.

Is this something as simple as k-nearest neighbor, and the training set consists of the one organization that I want to use to identify similar organizations? In other words, can I specify the cluster center as one organization? I use R for my analysis.

Answer (score 1):

Something similar to k-nearest-neighbor, as you said, would be a reasonable way to approach it. Without running a k-nearest-neighbor algorithm explicitly, you can easily calculate the Euclidian (or Mahalanobis, Manhattan, Minowski, or Hamming) distance between the new organization and each of the organizations already in the data set and choose the N organizations with the smallest distance.

Answer (score 1):

An alternate solution to your problem could be running k-means clustering with pre-calculated centroids.

I assume, based on the earlier clustering analysis you will have access to certain features. You may use them and find closest matches.

Comment: Great idea. This algorithm is also known as K-Means++